# Chartjs Line Chart showing old data when hovering

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js

I have a line chart that's created using chart.js. Everything works fine on page load, but when toggle the chart and hover to chart's corners, it shows old charts.

Also here is the live webapp that you can see the behavior.
https://www.batchrank.com/

I tried to fix with update(), destroy and clear however non of them worked.

Thanks a lot for the help,

Here is my code;

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("chartContainer").getContext("2d");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: "line",
        data: {
            label: "data",
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Mobile Speed Scores",
                    data: mobileData,
                    backgroundColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)"],
                    borderColor: ["rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)"],
                    borderWidth: 1
                },
                {
                    label: "Desktop Speed Scores",
                    data: desktopData,
                    backgroundColor: ["rgba(49, 67, 129, 0.2)"],
                    borderColor: ["rgba(49, 67, 129, 1)"],
                    borderWidth: 1
                }
            ]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: inspectUrl
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [
                    {
                        type: "time",
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "Date"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                yAxes: [
                    {
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: "value"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    });

    myChart.render();
    const removeElements = elms => elms.forEach(el => el.remove());
    removeElements(document.querySelectorAll(".progress"));

    function toogleDataSeries(e) {
        e.dataSeries.visible = !(
            typeof e.dataSeries.visible === "undefined" || e.dataSeries.visible
        );
      myChart.destroy();
        myChart.render();

    }
}
```